# this.variable is not defined even after binding the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-native-ios

React Native keeps saying `this.lns` is not defined, but I've tried binding the function `renderButtons`. I've researched multiple times as well, and they keep saying to add arrow functions or bind the function, which I seem to have already tried. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've already tried `this.renderButtons.bind(this)` in multiple places, including the constructor for my component. At this point I'm not sure what to do!

Here is the error:
**Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError: this.lns is undefined**

This is the Menu file code - the renderButtons() function seems to be causing an issue.
https://pastebin.com/JN7ERCE7
This is the Lessons file code:
https://pastebin.com/wbt0wrbb

The renderButtons function:

```
renderButtons(){
    const views = [];

    views.push(
      <Text key="free_label" style={{fontSize: 18}}>Free Fundemental Lessons: </Text>
    );

    for ( var i =0; i<this.lns.free.length; i++){
     views.push(
        <Button
           key={"freeLesson_" + String(i)}
           onPress={() => this.createLessonView.bind(this, () => this.lns.free[i])}
           title={() => this.lns.free[i].title}
           color="#000000"
        />);
        console.log(() => this.lns.free[i].title);
    }

    views.push(
      <Text key={"premiumLabel"} style={{fontSize: 18}}>Premium Lessons: </Text>
    );

    for ( var i =0; i<this.lns.all.length; i++){
      views.push(
         <Button
            key={"premiumLesson_" + String(i)}
            onPress={() => this.createLessonView.bind(this, () => this.lns.all[i])}
            title={() => this.lns.all[i].title}
            color="#841584"
         />);
     }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {views}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I expect the output in the simulator in XCode for my app to output:
Free Fundamental Lessons:
(LIST OF LESSONS AS BUTTONS HERE)
Premium Lessons:
(LIST OF PREMIUM LESSONS HERE)

I am kind of new to StackOverflow and React Native by the way.

Comment: no where in the snipplet do we see where lns is set.

Comment: okay so `this.lns = LessonHandler.getLessons();` shows it in the external source

Comment: You have `this.renderButtons = this.renderButtons.bind(this);` twice, get rid of the one in render

Comment: you should not bind render, it's a lifecycle method

Comment: I posted the rest of the code on pastebin since stack overflow told me I should not post the whole code here. The lessons file is not important as the whole error points to the renderButtons function.

Answer (score 1):

Change var in the `for ( var i =0; i<this.lns.all.length; i++){` to `let`.
This will create local binding instead of the global, which getting overwritten in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, it did change the error from this.lns is not defined to cannot read property free of undefined. I'm going to try to check the code again right now.

Comment: Hey, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/qv4mp51y6.
For  the future create sandbox example of the problem, rather than copy paste.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that does help a lot, however, with my current code I am having a new issue where it prints out {"all":[],"free":[]} from within Menu
It should be printing out the lessons as before it worked by printing out the lessons within my lessons file. Should I edit my post here or create a new issue on StackOverflow?